# Como fazer foreach em cada select usando EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Segue o código:

```
var list = new List<String>();
list.Add("Casa");
list.Add("Apartamento");

var connection = ctx.Table.Where(x => x.Tipo== list).ToList();
```

Meu banco de dados:

```
+=============================================+
|      Tipo     |    TBName   |    Número     |
+=============================================+
| Sandwich Type | Turkey Club |            10 |
| Casa          | Italian     |             5 |
| Casa          | Garlic      |             8 |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução que eu achei foi:

Primeiro você lista tudo e depois você aplica o filtro.

```
var list = new List<String>();
list.Add("Casa");
list.Add("Apartamento");

var connection = ctx.Table.ToList().Where(x =>list.Contains(x.Tipo)).ToList();
```

Comment: Tiago S, thanks